# JS перебор массива, вывод в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, массивы

Из БД получаю 5 массивов в виде:

1. Корм, Поводок.
2. Кг. Шт. и т.п.

Мне надо перебрать все массивы и подставить в HTML.

На PHP это реализуется за минуту, с JS затупил.

Собираю массивы, на выходе получаю:

```
 {0: ["Корм", "Поводок"], 1: ["Шт.", "Кг."], 2: ["1", "12"], 3: ["23", "111"], 4: ["23.00", "1332.00"]}
```

А мне нужно, разделить все массивы, чтобы получился первый массив

```
 {0: ["Корм"], 1: ["Шт."], 2: ["1"], 3: ["23"], 4: ["23.00"]}
```

второй массив уже `Поводок` и т.п., чтобы можно было в HTML вставить.

```js
var moneyName = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneyName);
var moneyType = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneyType);
var moneyCost = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneyCost);
var moneyAmount = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneyAmount);
var moneySum = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneySum);

//Очищаем форму
$('#set__money').html('');

//Собираю единый массив
var dataRow = [moneyName, moneyType, moneyCost, moneyAmount, moneySum];
var obj = {};
$(dataRow).each(function(e, i) {
  obj[e] = i;
});
```

Comment: То есть вам нужно обрезать массив, или сделать два массива?

Comment: По хорошему мне нужно взять 5 массивов, в каждом из них может быть от 1 записи до n, объединить эти массивы в один, затем в html подставлять данные из этого единого массива, но нужно чтобы в один блок подставлялись данные из этого массива в виде  (0:1, 1:1, 2:1), проходим цикл и далее подставляем (0:2, 1:2, 2:2) и т.д.

Comment: Поводки в килограммах, корм в штуках? ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен ))) может кому - то пригодится. 
На красоту и элегантность не притендую.

```js
//Получаем массивы из БД
var moneyName = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneyName);
var moneyType = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneyType);
var moneyCost = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneyCost);
var moneyAmount = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneyAmount);
var moneySum = jQuery.parseJSON(result.moneySum);

//Собираем все массивы в один
var dataRow = [moneyName, moneyType, moneyCost, moneyAmount, moneySum];

var i = 0;
var obj = [];
//Проходим циклом по собранному массиву
for (var el, i = 0; i < dataRow.length; i++) {
  el = dataRow[i];
  //Перебираем массив и записываем в obj
  $(el).each(function(e, i) {
    obj[e] = i;
    //Получаем новый массив obj[0] с первыми элементами
    console.log(obj[0]);
  });
}
//obj[1] - следующий массив и т.д.
```

Comment: чё-т каша какая-то

Comment: Я же говорю, не претендую. Если предложите лучший вариант, только буду благодарен.

Comment: так и я не настаиваю, просто совсем не ясно что там происходит, не смотря на комментарии

Comment: Нет нужды в jQuery, если она используется только для парсинга джейсонов... можно использовать стандартный `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const { wire,bind } = hyperHTML
// --
window.addEventListener('load',() => {
  let matrix = [["Корм","Поводок"],["Шт.","Кг."],["1","12"],["23","111"],["23.00","1332.00"]]

  let matrix2 = ref(matrix)

  let table = genHTMLTableElement(matrix2)
  table.classList.add('qwa')

  let style = genStyle()

  let body = bind(document.body) `${style}${table}`
})

function genHTMLTableElement(_matrix){
  let Td = (_str) => wire() `<td>${_str}</td>`
  let Tr = (_arr) => wire() `<tr>${_arr}</tr>`
  let Table = (_arr) => wire() `<table>${_arr}</table>`
  let table = null
  let tr = []
  for (let arr of _matrix) {
    let arrTd = []
    for (let _str of arr) {
      arrTd.push(Td(_str))
    }
    tr.push(Tr(arrTd))
  }
  table = Table(tr)
  return table
}

function ref(_matrix){
  let matrix2 = Array.from(Array(_matrix[0].length),() => [])
  for (let _arr of _matrix) {
    for (var _i = 0; _i < _arr.length; _i++) {
      matrix2[_i].push(_arr[_i])
    }
  }
  return matrix2
}

function genStyle(){
  return wire()`
  <style>
    .qwa { border:solid 1px; }
    .qwa td { border-bottom:solid 1px; }
    .qwa tr:hover { background-color: #d7f7f7; }
  </style>`
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hyperhtml@latest/min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А без сторонних библиотек? на js или jquery?

Comment: @ВладимирЛебединский, могу на js но будет длинннееее ...